# Why is the time displayed in my achievements notification area 1 hour behind the actual time?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications

In my achievements notification area it says that the current time is `14:34`, however all the clocks in my house say that it is currently `15:34`, so it seems that it thinks that I am in a timezone which is an hour behind, why is this, and is there any fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in UTC time, the time on which all of SE ticks. It's not local time and no there is no "fix".

Comment: Well, there should be a way of setting your own local timezone so that the time can be displayed correctly there.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda The point is not to display the local time, the point is to give you a reference for what time it is for the site

Comment: But, why? What's the point?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda As I said in my last comment, the point is to give a reference for site wide time.  Most notably so you can know when scripts are going to run and when the new UTC day begins (and all your daily limits reset).

Comment: @ParanoidPanda you asked a question fairly recently about a certain daily limit. Surely the time when the limit is reset matters for you?

Comment: @muru: Well, I would assume (and want if not already the case) that those would be changed for my detected timezone.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Rate limits and system jobs that effect the entire network are not and should not be adaptable to your local timezone, that would completely upset the balance of the site and system.